# Overlap two div in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I saw many Q/A in Stackoverflow but not getting solution!!

[image]

Above image is my desired design.Total white space is a `container` of Bootstrap. And two div will contain in it with full width of the `container`. Their width are not matter like `col-md-7` and `col-md-5` and anything.

I have tried some:

```
<div class="container">

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="FirstDIV">
                    abcd
                </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 overlay-text">
              <img src="#" height="auto" class="w-100"/>
              <button>Abc</button>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
.overlay-text {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding:20px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.FirstDIV {
  background-color: #FDC9B3;
  transform: translateX(15%); 
  height: 200px;
}
```

```css
.overlay-text {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding:20px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.FirstDIV {
  background-color: #FDC9B3;
  transform: translateX(15%); 
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="FirstDIV">
                    abcd
                </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 overlay-text">
              <img src="https://d1v3slut4s2mfy.cloudfront.net/4febbf2819ab561801f175b47cf75b3413985518/assets/images/quote-video-placeholder.jpg" height="auto" class="w-100"/>
              <button>Abc</button>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n8cj4o3d/

**Mainly `transform: translateX(15%);` is creating problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the container element. And then add `position: absolute` to the child divs. Now you can position the child divs wherever you want using the `top, left, right, bottom` properties.

Comment: Main problem is to use ```position: absolute;```--- Next section is coming to up and overlap with this content.

Comment: And total width is not getting because of ```transform: translateX(15%);```

Comment: Can you produce your code in a CodePen or JsFiddle? It'll be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not take both of them in the `row`.

```
<div class="overlay-text">
     <img src="#" height="auto" class="w-100"/>
     <button>Abc</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="FirstDIV">
             abcd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  padding:20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 10%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/41v5Lde8/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also give position: relative to the parent div

```css
.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, 20%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.FirstDIV {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FDC9B3;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #FDC9B3;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="FirstDIV">
        abcd
        <div class="overlay-text">
          <img src="https://d1v3slut4s2mfy.cloudfront.net/4febbf2819ab561801f175b47cf75b3413985518/assets/images/quote-video-placeholder.jpg" height="auto" class="w-100" />
          <button>Abc</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```